# Set object's nested object's proerty as combo valuemember

Tags: c#, combobox, valuemember

I have a combobox. Its datasource a list of objects. This class has a public property that is a class defined by me. I would like to set combo's valuemember to a property of this class. How can I do that?

```
class B
{
public int Id {get; set;}
}

class A
{
public B AnyProperty {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}

var testList = new List<A>() {...};
combo.DataSource = testList;
combo.DisplayMemver = "Name";
combo.ValueMember = ??? //it should be A.AnyProperty.Id
```

.Net4/VS2010/C#

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
combo.ValueMember = "AnyProperty";
```

Combobox will bind an object. You can then get the value back by doing something like this.

```
var selectedValue = (B)combobox.SelectValue;
```

Please not that the above sytax maybe be incorrect.